# Why is ruby not raising the exception?

Tags: ruby, exception

I have the following code:

```
require 'open-uri'

class CustomException < StandardError;end

def file
  f = Kernel.open('http://i.dbastatic.dk/images/2/68/500656768_20012012182407_0401_2.jpg')
  return f
rescue => e
  raise CustomException.new(e.message)
end
```

Now if I do the following:

```
begin
  file.body
rescue CustomException
  puts "rescued it!"
end
```

I get:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass

Instead of the the CustomException with the 404 error message from open uri. The strange thing is, that if I instead do:

```
begin
  f = file
  f.body
rescue CustomException
  puts "rescued it!"
end
```

Then it works, I get the CustomException, that I can catch, before it's trying to do the .body. I don't get why? And how can I change the file-method to do as I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've confused yourself. The only code you've shown that seems to illustrate the problem is this:

```
require 'open-uri'

class CustomException < StandardError;end

def file
  f = Kernel.open('http://www.google.com/blahblah')
  return f
rescue => e
  raise CustomException.new(e.message)
end

begin
  file.body
rescue CustomException
  puts "rescued it!"
end
```

Well, I ran that code, and I got "rescued it!" Isn't that what one would expect? I never get `NoMethodError: undefined method body for nil:NilClass` and I don't believe that you do, either, with the code you show.

So what's the problem, really? Is it that the 404 message isn't getting passed out to stdout? If that's what you wanted, you should have written:

```
require 'open-uri'

class CustomException < StandardError;end

def file
  f = Kernel.open('http://www.google.com/blahblah')
  return f
rescue => e
  raise CustomException.new(e.message)
end

begin
  file.body
rescue CustomException => e
  puts "rescued it!", e.message
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a little modification  to show the problem:

```
require 'open-uri'

def file
  f = Kernel.open('fill_in_some_url_that_returns_a_404')
  return f
rescue => e
  puts e.message
  1 ##<<---- inserted
end

file.body
```

No you get a `undefined method 'body' for 1:Fixnum`

Explanation:
Your method does the `puts e.message`, but it does not return a result (or in other words: it returns `nil`.)

With `file.body` you call `file` (with the result `nil`). and on this result you call `body`. But this does not exist for `nil`. So you get the error `undefined method 'body' for nil:NilClass`

If I try

```
f = file
f.body
```

I get the same error.

Are you sure, you use the same url in both calls? If you can open your url, the you retrun a valid object.

---

Actually I can't see your problem without more code.

You could check your code for one thing:

If you define a variable *and* a method `file`, then you get the variable. See example below. Perhaps this is the problem.

```
file = nil
def file
  1
end

file.body   #undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
file().body #undefined method `body' for 1:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

To be sure to get the method you can try `file()`.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad, it was a bad example. I ended up over simplifying what I was actually trying to do. Now i edited my question to better fit the actual situation... Please have a look again :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:

```
require 'open-uri'

def file(url)
 begin
  Kernel.open(url)
 rescue => e
  puts e.message
 end
end
```

Let's try a valid url first:

```
f = file('http://www.google.com/')
puts f.read if !f.nil?
```

And now let's try it with a url that returns a 404:

```
f = file('http://www.google.com/blahblah')
puts f.read if !f.nil?
```

Edit: Your code raises two errors when called on non-existing URLs. The 'file' method raises a OpenURI::HTTPError, while the 'body' method will raise a NoMethodError because it's called on nil. In your first usage example, you raise those two errors in one statement. In the second usage example, the errors are sequential. Still, they should yield the same result and they do for me.

Comment: Okay, But I would expect the first one to interrupt further execution and be raised - Wouldn't you? and what should I do to change the file method still so I can do file.body, and still get the first exception out

Comment: Yes, execution is halted after the first exception. Generally speaking, you need to narrow down the exceptions you want to recover from. It doesn't make much sense to recover from a NoMethodError, for instance. Just check for nil objects outside method definitions.